# is this also an example of anonymous derived class? (java basics)

Tags: java, android

This is a sample code from Android developers website:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    /** The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
      * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute() */
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    /** The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
      * the result from doInBackground() */
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Here, in the line `new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://example.com/image.png");`, does `new DownloadImageTask()` create an object of the `DownloadImageTask` class, or does it create an annonymous class that extends `DownloadImageTask`?

For comparison:
In this code,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Bitmap b = loadImageFromNetwork("http://example.com/image.png");
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

an object of a class derived from the Thread class has been made and instantiated, but without saving a reference to it (which makes it so that it cannot be used again in the future), instead of an object of type Thread. What is the case in the former code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does `new DownloadImageTask()` create an object of the `DownloadImageTask` class

Yes. As it's an *inner* class, it will implicitly pass the current enclosing instance to the (hidden) constructor, but that's all that's even slightly unusual about that constructor call.

An anonymous class creation expression always uses `new Something() { ... }` with the braces.

From [section 15.9.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1):

> If the class instance creation expression ends in a class body, then the class being instantiated is an anonymous class.

Answer (score 3):

it creates an object of the DownloadImageTask.

It would be an anonymous class if it looked like this:

```
new DownloadImageTask(){ ... }.execute()
```